# Problem with authentication with useMemo and useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I have a with my authentication script.
I want to prepare an authentication using AuthContext.

I want check that user is login for each pages, and added token when user log-in, and remove when log-out - it is good practices?

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
const cookies = new Cookies();

// get token generated on login
const token = cookies.get("TOKEN");

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(null);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // useEffect automatically executes once the page is fully loaded
  useEffect(() => {
    // set configurations for the API call here
    const configuration = {
      method: "get",
      url: "http://localhost:3005/auth-endpoint",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    };

    // make the API call
    axios(configuration)
      .then((result) => {
        setLoggedIn(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        error = new Error();
        setLoggedIn(false);
      });
  }, [loggedIn]);

  const login = async (data) => {
    const email = data.email;
    const password = data.password;

    // set configurations
    const configuration = {
      method: "post",
      url: "http://localhost:3005/login",
      data: {
        email,
        password,
      },
    };

    // make the API call
    axios(configuration)
      .then((result) => {
        // set the cookie
        cookies.set("TOKEN", result.data.token, {
          path: "/",
        });
        // redirect user to the auth page
        setLoggedIn(true);
        navigate("/dashboard/profile", { replace: true });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        error = new Error();
      });
  };

  const logout = () => {
    // setUser(null);
    setLoggedIn(null);
    cookies.remove("TOKEN", { path: "/" });
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  };

  const value = useMemo(
    () => ({
      login,
      logout,
    }),
    []
  );

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};
```

At the moment code is not working,
useSate not changed when I logged, logout etc.

What I should fix?

Comment: Login and logout are driven by user interactions, you really don't need a `useEffect` to handle that, event handler is enough. `useMemo` is for caching expensive calculations, you don't need that either.

Comment: @lastoix61 Did my solution work for you? If so, do you mind mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1):

In the authprovider you shouldn't be using useEffect hook.

Here's my AuthProvider:
I am using a localStorage Hook instead of cookies.

```
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import { useLocalStorage } from '../hooks/useLocalStorage';
import { invalidateToken } from '../services/some.service';

type PropsType = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

interface AuthContextType {
  user: any;
  login: (userInfo: any, callback: VoidFunction) => void;
  logout: (callback: VoidFunction) => void;
}

let AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>(null!);
const sessionName = 'someKEY';  

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: PropsType) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useLocalStorage(sessionName, null);

  // call this function when you want to authenticate the user
  const login = (userInfo: any, callback: VoidFunction) => {
    setUser(userInfo);
    callback();
  };

  // call this function to sign out logged in user
  const logout = (callback: VoidFunction) => {
    const userToken = user;
    setUser(null);
    callback();
    invalidateToken(userToken);
  };

  const value = { login, logout, user };

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};
```

Then I created a component name ProtectedRoute, which will wrap every route that needs authentication:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { validateToken } from '../../services/some.service';
import { useAuth } from '../../providers/AuthProvider';    
export const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }: PropsType) => {
  const { user } = useAuth();

  const isValidLogin = (info: any): boolean => {
    if (!info) return false;
    else {
      // If you need to do something
    }
  };

  if (!isValidLogin(user)) {
    return <Navigate to="/app/login" />;
  }
  return children;
};
```

Finally in the Router:

```
 <AuthProvider>
    <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/app/somepath"
          element={
            <ProtectedRoute>
              <SomePage />
            </ProtectedRoute>
          }
        />
     </Routes>
  </AuthProvider>
```

You may use the AuthProvider in any component like this:

```
  const auth = useAuth();
  const onSignOut = () => {
    auth.logout(() => {});
  };
```

Comment: The callback function is interesting, I wonder how do you handle it when it comes to try catch in network calls. Let's say, the callback takes in navigate and toast functionalities. If network succeded, it navigates to new page, if it fails, it pops up a notification. Where does it fit in in the `login` function? (And in such situation, pass in those functions directly seems better?)

Comment: Login is just saving information in the localstorage to know if the user is valid or not.
In my project I need to verify the login with an OTP.
In this case I validate the otp, if successful then I call the login function of the AuthProvider, sending in the callback function the navigate.

If unsuccessful then I can show the toast. In this case, I won't be calling the authprovider.

Comment: Ah, I see, I didn't notice the `ProtectedRoute` set up.